# Integer does not compare when not equals

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, integer, compare

I have a method that calculate the next top score within an array of students by taking in the `student`array and `topStudentIndex`as parameters, which is calculated by another method for `topStudentIndex` in my main.

Below is my method:

```
public static int calNextHighestOverallStudentIndex(Student[] st, int topStudentIndex) {

    double nextHighestOverall= 0;
    int secondHighestStudentIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
        if ((st[i] != null) && (!(st[i].getStudentIndex() == topStudentIndex))) {
            System.out.println(topStudentIndex+ " compare with i = "+i);
            double currentOverall= st[i].getOverall();
            if (currentOverall> nextHighestOverall) {
                nextHighestOverall= currentOverall;
                secondHighestStudentIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    return secondHighestStudentIndex ;
}
```

I take in the index position of the top student, and checks if the array position is empty && same index. If not, the check will proceed.

However, the output shows that the comparison of index position is not working.

```
1 compare with i = 0
1 compare with i = 1
1 compare with i = 2
1 compare with i = 3
1 compare with i = 4
1 compare with i = 5
1 compare with i = 6
```

I have tried using `!=`and my current way of checking but to no avail.

Comment: You're comparing `st[i].getStudentIndex()`, not `i`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((st[i] != null) && (!(st[i].getStudentIndex() == topStudentIndex))) {
            System.out.println(topStudentIndex+ " compare with i = "+i);
```

You are comparing `topStudentIndex` with `st[i].getStudentIndex()` but printing `i` in the print statement.

Either do

```
if ((st[i] != null) && (!(i == topStudentIndex)))
```

or print

```
 System.out.println(topStudentIndex+ " compare with student index = "+ st[i].getStudentIndex());
```

to get clear idea why comparison fails.

Comment: thank you @Aniket. The comparison now worked. I met another issue with my for loop not looping. I will post the question in another thread. Thank you once again